# Powershell to get IIS application initialization status

Tags: powershell, iis, wmi, iis-6

My site has `doAppInitAfterRestart` set to `true` and is working, but I'd like to know when the application has completed it's initialization.

Is there a way through `powershell` and `WMI` to know when the site's application initialization is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned VB Script code. I have scraped this code from one of my working script , if you see any error, shoot a comment.

```
iis_con= "localhost"  
set WMI_IIS = GetObject( "IIS://" & iis_con & "/W3SVC" )
        if WMI_IIS.count = 0 then 
         ' do nothing
        else 
            for each objitem in WMI_IIS
                if objitem.class = "IIsWebServer" then
                    Select Case objItem.serverstate
                        Case 1:        wscript.echo("Starting")
                        Case 2:        wscript.echo("Running")
                        Case 3:        wscript.echo("Stopping")
                        Case 4:        wscript.echo("Stopped")
                        Case 5:        wscript.echo("Pausing")
                        Case 6:        wscript.echo("Paused")
                        Case 7:        wscript.echo("Continuing")
                        Case Default:  wscript.echo("Unknown")
                    End Select
                Next
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Amit. Doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.
Immediately after the site (less than a second) is started this code starts and continues to return "2" Running state.

Here is the code converted to powershell I was using to test with.
    while ( $true ) {
         $site=get-wmiobject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsWebServer" -ComputerName localhost -Filter "name='w3svc/4'" 
         $site.serverstate 
        start-sleep -Milliseconds 10 
    }

Comment: I was not aware that you were using IIS6+, so did not provide WMI. So are you facing any problem now? I did not quite figure out from your comment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using IIS6+. I'm still having problems determining when the app initialization is complete.